# Why app.config value null?

Tags: asp.net, configuration

I have a three tier web app that produces three separate dlls:

- Web.UI.dll
- Web.Application.dll
- Web.DAL.dll

Both `Web.Application.dll` and `Web.DAL.dll` have their own app.configs.  I need to access a specific setting that lives in web.config.  I am using the following code:

```
[CacheUtil.cs]
string cacheName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CacheName");
```

I have verified that this setting exists.  So, why then, when I run am I getting NULL?  Does CacheName need to exist in all of .config files?

Here is the setting in web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="CacheName" value="staging"/>
```

FYI, CacheUtil is a singleton that is lazy initialized upon first access.  First access is happening in the DAL.dll project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only `web.config` is being read. The other config files (`Web.Application.dll.config` and `Web.DAL.config`) are *not* read.

Config is not attached to libraries; only to the ultimate executable being run (the `AppName.exe.config` or `web.config`)

Projects in Visual Studio that produce an EXE can have an `app.config` file, and this file is treated specially upon build; It is renamed to `ProgramName.exe.config` and copied to the output directory. `app.config` in class library or Web application projects will have no effect.

Comment: Hmm, curious.  It seems to read fine in debug mode, but not after publishing.  So, the app.configs are meaningless?

Comment: `app.config` is meant for projects that produce an EXE. Part of the build process is that it gets renamed to `ProgramName.exe.config` and copied to the output directory. Web applications are different - instead of looking for `ProgramName.exe.config`, they look for `web.config`. Having `app.config` files in a class library project is meaningless, without copying the values contained therein to an appropriate config file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cachename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheName"];
```

This is provided that you are trying to read `AppSettings` out of the project's app.config file.  You can't read config from another project unless you use some other logic, but it wouldn't be through the ConfigurationManager class.  It'd have to be normal I/O.